# Optaplanner 7.13.0 cant be executed from a jar file

Tags: drools, optaplanner

I am building a project using optaplanner jar to solve a vehicle routing problem. After building the jar, I am unable to invoke the main class and this is the error I get:

```
513 [main] INFO org.kie.api.internal.utils.ServiceDiscoveryImpl - Loading kie.conf from  jar:file:/Users/meena/Documents/SourceCode/Comma_code/comma_code/sources/target/comma-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar!/META-INF/kie.conf in classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@55f96302
515 [main] INFO org.kie.api.internal.utils.ServiceDiscoveryImpl - Adding Service +org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.kie.KieSolverAssemblerService

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at org.kie.api.internal.utils.ServiceRegistry.getInstance(ServiceRegistry.java:27)
at org.kie.api.KieServices$Factory$LazyHolder.<clinit>(KieServices.java:332)
at org.kie.api.KieServices$Factory.get(KieServices.java:339)
at org.optaplanner.core.config.score.director.ScoreDirectorFactoryConfig.buildDroolsScoreDirectorFactory(ScoreDirectorFactoryConfig.java:499)
at org.optaplanner.core.config.score.director.ScoreDirectorFactoryConfig.buildScoreDirectorFactory(ScoreDirectorFactoryConfig.java:350)
at org.optaplanner.core.config.solver.SolverConfig.buildSolver(SolverConfig.java:255)
at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.AbstractSolverFactory.buildSolver(AbstractSolverFactory.java:61)
at com.abc.planner.app.UavRoutingApp.<init>(UavRoutingApp.java:57)
at com.abc.planner.app.UavRoutingApp.main(UavRoutingApp.java:110)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Child     services [org.kie.api.internal.assembler.KieAssemblers] have no parent
at org.kie.api.internal.utils.ServiceDiscoveryImpl.buildMap(ServiceDiscoveryImpl.java:180)
at org.kie.api.internal.utils.ServiceDiscoveryImpl.getServices(ServiceDiscoveryImpl.java:97)
at org.kie.api.internal.utils.ServiceRegistryImpl.<init>(ServiceRegistryImpl.java:36)
at org.kie.api.internal.utils.ServiceRegistryImpl$LazyHolder.<clinit>(ServiceRegistryImpl.java:32)
... 9 more
```

I have looked into Stackoverflow questions but was unable to find a solution that resolved it.

Here is a copy of my POM file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.abc</groupId>
<artifactId>proj_xyz</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>comma</name>
<url>http://www.barnstormresearch.com</url>

<!-- see https://www.optaplanner.org/download/download.html for planner version and mvn dependency
-->
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.optaplanner</groupId>
        <artifactId>optaplanner-core</artifactId>
        <version>7.13.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--dependency>
        <groupId>org.optaplanner</groupId>
        <artifactId>optaplanner-persistence-common</artifactId>
        <version>7.13.0.Final</version>
    </dependency-->
    <dependency><!-- Most examples use the XStream integration -->
        <groupId>org.optaplanner</groupId>
        <artifactId>optaplanner-persistence-xstream</artifactId>
        <version>7.13.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--dependency>
        <groupId>org.optaplanner</groupId>
        <artifactId>optaplanner-benchmark</artifactId>
        <version>7.13.0.Final</version>
    </dependency-->
    <!--dependency>
        <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
        <artifactId>kie-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.12.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
        <artifactId>drools-decisiontables</artifactId>
        <version>7.12.0.Final</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>20.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Logging -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.25</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.4</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- see http://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0</version>
            <!-- set the java version -->
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.20.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <!--plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin-->
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <mainClass>
                            com.abc.planner.app.UavRoutingApp
                        </mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

It is executing from the IDE. I have extracted the jar files and found only 1 META_INF/kie.conf

Any ideas are really appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

It looks like a drools and Uber-jar(or fat-jar or one-jar) issue. I found this on the drools documentation site:

https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/7.14.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/index.html#_building_and_running_drools_in_a_fat_jar

This is a much simpler fix than some of the others suggested.

I made the change suggested here and used the maven shade plugin to build a single jar and it works now. I am pasting my sample pom file for other users who will run into this issue:

Add this to the maven-shade-plugin section:

```
<transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
    <resource>META-INF/kie.conf</resource>
</transformer>
```

### My final pom.xml

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <!-- Run shade goal on package phase -->
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <!-- add Main-Class to manifest file -->
                                <transformer
                                        implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>com.abc.planner.app.UavRoutingApp</mainClass>

                                    <!-- -Dlog4j.configurationFile=../properties/idStrikeSolver-log4j.properties -Duser.timezone="UTC" -->
                                </transformer>
                                <transformer
                                        implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                    <resource>META-INF/kie.conf</resource>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Hope this helps others too! Thanks for your help Geoffrey.

Comment: Thanks for sharing!

Comment: This worked for me with some changes. Note that the shade plugin must run *after* the assembly plugin.

Comment: Thanks for sharing! This worked for me. Note that the shade plugin must run *instead* of the assembly plugin. ;)

Answer (score 1):

`Drools` and `jar-with-dependencies` aren't compatible AFAIK.

Workarounds:

- A different score calculation like constraint streams, easy java (too slow) or incremental java (too painfull).
- Don't use `jar-with-dependencies`

Comment: Thanks for the response Geoffrey. I changed the pom file to use "shaded-plugin" and that is not working either. For some reason, 7.1.0 OptaPlanner works (even with jar-with-dependecies). Is there anything else I can try?