# IllegalArgumentException when exporting OptaPlanner as jar

Tags: optaplanner

I am trying to export the OptaPlanner's ProjectJobScheduling example as an executable jar file but I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The solverConfigResource (org/optaplanner/examples/projectjobscheduling/solver/projectJobSchedulingSolverConfig.xml) does not exist as a classpath resource in the classLoader (jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@c387f44).
    at org.optaplanner.core.config.solver.SolverConfig.createFromXmlResource(SolverConfig.java:107)
    at org.optaplanner.core.config.solver.SolverConfig.createFromXmlResource(SolverConfig.java:85)
    at org.optaplanner.core.api.solver.SolverFactory.createFromXmlResource(SolverFactory.java:60)
    at org.optaplanner.examples.common.app.CommonApp.createSolverFactory(CommonApp.java:135)
    at org.optaplanner.examples.common.app.CommonApp.createSolutionBusiness(CommonApp.java:123)
    at org.optaplanner.examples.common.app.CommonApp.init(CommonApp.java:114)
    at org.optaplanner.examples.common.app.CommonApp.init(CommonApp.java:110)
    at org.optaplanner.examples.projectjobscheduling.app.ProjectJobSchedulingApp.main(ProjectJobSchedulingApp.java:36)
```

I have looked through all related questions on StackOverflow but I couldn't manage to solve the problem. This is a part of the ProjectJobSchedulingApp code:

```
    public static final String SOLVER_CONFIG
            = "org/optaplanner/examples/projectjobscheduling/solver/projectJobSchedulingSolverConfig.xml";

    public static final String DATA_DIR_NAME = "projectjobscheduling";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        prepareSwingEnvironment();
        new ProjectJobSchedulingApp().init();
    }

    public ProjectJobSchedulingApp() {
        super("Project job scheduling",
                "Official competition name:" +
                        " multi-mode resource-constrained multi-project scheduling problem (MRCMPSP)\n\n" +
                        "Schedule all jobs in time and execution mode.\n\n" +
                        "Minimize project delays.",
                SOLVER_CONFIG, DATA_DIR_NAME,
                ProjectJobSchedulingPanel.LOGO_PATH);
    }
```

How could I resolve this issue? Perhaps I am creating the jar file in the wrong manner?

**Edit:** 
Geoffrey thanks for you tip, it solved the problem. Now a new problem occured which is the same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53199223/optaplanner-7-13-0-cant-be-executed-from-a-jar-file) one.  The solution suggested in there as well as the solution suggested by Yurloc don't work. This is the code of my pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.optaplanner</groupId>
    <artifactId>optaplanner</artifactId>
    <version>7.29.0.Final</version>
  </parent>

  <artifactId>optaplanner-examples</artifactId>

  <name>OptaPlanner examples</name>
  <description>
    OptaPlanner solves planning problems.
    This lightweight, embeddable planning engine implements powerful and scalable algorithms
    to optimize business resource scheduling and planning.

    This module contains the examples which demonstrate how to use it in a normal Java application.
  </description>
  <url>https://www.optaplanner.org</url>

  <properties>
    <java.module.name>org.optaplanner.examples</java.module.name>
  </properties>

  <repositories>
    <!-- Included so the examples sources in the distribution zip build out-of-the-box with maven -->
    <repository>
      <id>jboss-public-repository-group</id>
      <name>JBoss Public Repository Group</name>
      <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
      <layout>default</layout>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <updatePolicy>daily</updatePolicy>
      </snapshots>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <configuration>
            <forkCount>0.5C</forkCount>
            <systemPropertyVariables>
              <java.awt.headless>true</java.awt.headless>
            </systemPropertyVariables>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
          <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <!-- WARNING: This configuration must be run with "mvn exec:java" not "mvn exec:exec". -->
          <!-- It is impossible to write a configuration that is compatible with both exec:java and exec:exec -->
          <configuration>
            <mainClass>org.optaplanner.examples.app.OptaPlannerExamplesApp</mainClass>
            <arguments>
              <argument>-Xms256m</argument>
              <!-- Most examples run (potentially slower) with max heap of 128 MB (so -Xmx128m), but 1 example's dataset requires 1.5 GB -->
              <argument>-Xmx1536m</argument>
              <argument>-server</argument>
            </arguments>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
          </descriptorRefs>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>

  <dependencies>
    <!-- Internal dependencies -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.optaplanner</groupId>
      <artifactId>optaplanner-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.optaplanner</groupId>
      <artifactId>optaplanner-persistence-common</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency><!-- Most examples use the XStream integration -->
      <groupId>org.optaplanner</groupId>
      <artifactId>optaplanner-persistence-xstream</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency><!-- TODO add examples that use the JAXB integration -->
      <groupId>org.optaplanner</groupId>
      <artifactId>optaplanner-persistence-jaxb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency><!-- TODO add examples that use the jackson integration -->
      <groupId>org.optaplanner</groupId>
      <artifactId>optaplanner-persistence-jackson</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.optaplanner</groupId>
      <artifactId>optaplanner-benchmark</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.optaplanner</groupId>
      <artifactId>optaplanner-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
      <artifactId>kie-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
      <artifactId>drools-decisiontables</artifactId>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
      <artifactId>drools-canonical-model</artifactId>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
      <artifactId>drools-model-compiler</artifactId>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- External dependencies -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jfree</groupId>
      <artifactId>jfreechart</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Common utils -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
      <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Logging -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
      <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- XML -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
      <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Examples only dependencies. -->
    <!--
      WARNING: every examples only dependency must be properly dealt with in
      optaplanner-distribution/src/main/assembly/assembly-optaplanner.xml
    -->
    <!-- Converters -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jdom</groupId>
      <artifactId>jdom</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
      <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
      <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <!-- Collides with 'javax.xml.stream:stax-api' brought in by 'org.drools:drools-decisiontables'. -->
          <groupId>stax</groupId>
          <artifactId>stax-api</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.json</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

</project>
```

Comment: Unzip your executable jar. Does it contain `org/optaplanner/examples/projectjobscheduling/solver/projectJobSchedulingSolverConfig.xml`?

Comment: @GeoffreyDeSmet Yes `resources\org\optaplanner\examples\projectjobscheduling\solver` contains `projectJobSchedulingSolverConfix.xml`.

Comment: `resources/...`? It should start in the root of the jar (= zip file).

Comment: Yes it is only present in `resources\org\optaplanner\examples\projectjobscheduling\solver`, in `org\optaplanner\examples\projectjobscheduling\solver` it isn't present. (Both starting in the root of the jar)

Comment: So it's not where it should be :)

Answer (score 1):

You're probably making a mistake in how you build the executable JAR. Please share the relevant code (probably `pom.xml` or `assembly.xml`) or try to add this to your `optaplanner-examples/pom.xml`:

```xml
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
          </descriptorRefs>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <mainClass>org.optaplanner.examples.projectjobscheduling.app.ProjectJobSchedulingApp</mainClass>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Comment: Adding your suggested code didn't solve the problem. I have added my pom.xml file in my initial question.